# Как изменить расположение текста в input

Tags: html, css, input

[image: фото того что вышло у меня]
надо сделать так чтоб в input текст сразу начинал вводиться вверху а не по середине, спасибо

```
html
<input type="text" placeholder="Type your message" class="sub_contacts_message">
```

```
css
.sub_contacts_message {
   height: 249px;
   width: 731px;
   margin-top: 46px;
   padding-left: 54px;
   font-size: 16px;
   font-weight: 400;
   border: none;
   border-radius: 7px;
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   color: #676767;
   background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
```

Comment: Никак, думается - поменяйте input на textarea, например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно, конечно и через `input` сделать, но придется JS подключать, самый просто вариант:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-group textarea {
  height: 249px;
  width: 731px;
  margin-top: 46px;
  padding-left: 54px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #676767;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <textarea placeholder="Type your text"></textarea>
</div>
```